# How to add active state to the navigation links?

Tags: customization, menus, navigation

I am trying to add active states for my custom menu navigation, but so far everything I try
is just not working. I have set the navigation menu in a separate file nav.php, 
then I included the nav.php into my header.php file like this:

```
<?php include('nav.php'); ?>
```

I created custom Wordpress pages in the child folder and included the header.php just after the template name:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Website Design Page*/
 ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
```

Here is my current html and php code in my nav.php and 
I added a unique id attribute "currentpage" to indicate which menu item reflects the user’s current page:

```
<ul id="menu" class="clearfix">                
                <li<?php if ($thisPage=="About") 
echo " id=\"currentpage\""; ?> class="parent-item"><a href="/about" title="Welcome page" class="parent-link menu-item-2" id="main-menu-item-4">About</a></li>                               

                <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Portfolio") 
echo " id=\"currentpage\""; ?> class="parent-item"><a href="/portfolio" class="parent-link menu-item-3">Portfolio</a></li>               

                <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Services") 
echo " id=\"currentpage\""; ?> class="parent-item"><a href="/services" class="parent-link menu-item-4">Services</a></li> 

                <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Prices") 
echo " id=\"currentpage\""; ?> class="parent-item"><a href="/prices" class="parent-link menu-item-5">Prices</a></li>                

</ul>
```

And this is my Css for hover and active states:

```
ul#menu li a:hover {
background-color: #999999;
color: #fff; 
}

ul#menu li #currentpage a {
background: #fff;
color: #333;
}
```

For each pages I assigned the value after the template name, here is my Home page:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Website Design Page
*/
 ?>
<?php $thisPage="Home"; ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
```

I hope somebody will be able to help, I really don't undestand why this code or any other php code i try
I cannot make these custom menus work.

Comment: Missing much code, such incomplete, wow - please edit the question so we can help.  Cheers.

Comment: Just as tip, when you add code in the editor, highlight your code and click on the `{}` sign just above the editor. This will add your code is a codeblock :-)

Comment: You need to make `$thisPage` global if you're going to reference it in other files, see [variable scope in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).  You generally want to avoid making anything else global if you can avoid it.  You're probably better off using built in WordPress tools for the menus as suggested by @Dan's answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your effort and the reference link you send for documentation. Yes, indeed, I believe it's better to use WordPress build in tools and hook into my styles to get the desired effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PHP file, set `$thisPage` before you `include('nav.php');`. Then, the variable `$thisPage` will be passed to `nav.php` and processed in its `if` statement.

This is *really* bad practice though, and a better way of doing it would be by creating your menu in WordPress itself and hooking it into your template. WordPress documents [how to do this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus) well.

Answer (score 1):

If your theme is using wp_nav_menu() you will have the class `current-menu-item` added to the relevant `<li>` element for you. Does this help?

Comment: Hi Dan, it is a custom menu with the id #menu, but I now changed it to wp_nav_menu and also made changes to css. Should I delete also this php code from all buleted li: <?php if ($thisPage=="About") 
echo " id=\"currentpage\""; ?>

Comment: Why don't you just use the `wp_nav_menu()` function instead of manually making your menu?

Comment: Hi Dan, you are right about using wp_nav_menu() function, 
rather than taking the hassle to manually make one. So I added the wordpress navigation back and I have this:
<div id="access" role="navigation">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
   </div>
now the only problem is when I get into styling the menus, first of all I cannot make it the menus float to right.

Comment: You will probably need to change your CSS selectors to work with the HTML that Wordpress makes for you. Normally the <ul> element has a class of "menu", not an id like your code example.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is remove all that code you have in *nav.php* displaying the menu, create the menu inside the Wordpress backend, then you'll be able to use `.current-menu-item` in your css.

Then all you need to call the menu will be `wp_nav_menu();`

Here is the documentation for that function:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the nav.php file from my header.php,
and added back the old menu code that comes with Wordpress.
I did some hooking into my style.css file to adjust the styles for the desired design
and I only used the #menu-navmenu that I created in WordPress to float right my menu bar.

```
ul#menu-navmenu{float: right;}
```

So before I had this ul#menu {float: right; margin: 15px;}

and now I added 15px margin to this code in wordpress style.css template:

```
#access .menu-header ul,
div.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    /*margin: 0;*/margin: 15px;
}
```

Everything works as expected and
thank you for all your help in this matter, this is a great WordPress community.